# Only allow 'business' email address register on website

Tags: validation, email, registration, verification

We are looking to build a new website that is specifically for commercial/business use.  We need to only allow 'business' email addresses register.  So users with Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo etc cannot apply with those email addresses.

Is there a way to do this, other than creating a blacklist of domains such as gmail.com, hotmail.com etc?  It will be an international site - so it will be impossible to blacklist all of the public email providers.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: What are you guys trying to achieve? Inability to register an address of their liking would turn potential users away from your web site. Besides, if someone would like to have e-mails from your site in his or her personal mailbox, they could use forwarding feature of their e-mail client to achieve that result with ease.

Comment: Hi all..to clarify - the site will be used by large commercial enterprises - for the purposes of purchasing services for their business. Essentially it would be used by IT / Procurement managers.  We need to qualify the people registering on the site and ensure they also have the proper 'internal' privileges before purchasing from the site - hence wanting to lock it down to only allowing business users.

Comment: I have the same problem: I want to filter out all the emails that has a public domain and make able to register only the ones that have a "private" domain. Did you find a solution other than the black list?

Comment: This is impossible. There is absolutely no way to tell whether a given email address is a "business" email address.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko in 2021 this is a very common requirement for signups for various services. E.g. snowflake is advertising a free "for dummies" book and to get it you must sign up with a "business email." When searching for a solution to this, I found an "email validator" company which, guess what, asks you to sign up with a business email address in order to get a free account. It seems like the solution is to sign up with a service that keeps its own whitelist/blacklist, rather than code it from scratch somehow.

Answer (score 14):

As others have stated, it doesn't really make much sense to try to detect a business customer based on his email domain, but if you really wanna go down that road, blacklisting is your best bet. The spamassassin freemail plugin provides a good default blacklist:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk/rules/20_freemail_domains.cf

Comment: Thanks, I have also found urlblacklist.com which may do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Small businesses are having `@gmail.com` addresses (and some people are not able to configure their `gmail` to redirect emitting email address to something else).

Some big businesses may have internal policies disallowing such subscriptions with the company email, so some people there would also use a `@gmail.com` address for that.

So I would not filter out such email addresses.

Comment: I second this. And how would anyone know that a certain domain belongs to a company rather than a public email provider (considering a small email provider)? I think if you are offering services only relevant to business users, there is no need to filter non-business users before they register. Because they would have no benefit of using your system.

Answer (score 2):

Private individuals occasionally run their own email servers as well. Consider:

a) Person (A) registers a domain from a registrar like gandi.net, and signs up for their email service and hosted blog.

b) Company (B) registers a domain from the same registrar and signs up for their email service.

There is *no* way for you to differentiate, technically, between these two. They will even share the same mail server [which *can* serve multiple domains].

Answer (score 2):

There are some online services which do provide these services (Email Verifications).
Take a look here:

---

1. https://emailhunter.co/email-verifier

Their API Documentation:
https://emailhunter.co/api/docs#email-verification

---

2. Another one is: https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io/

Answer (score 0):

I created a new list of free email providers using the spamassassin list, GPT and some scripts. Feel free to reuse if useful for someone else in the future https://github.com/pyrytakala/pyryresources/blob/master/free-email-providers.csv