# email field in Django only for corporate emails

Tags: django, authentication

Guys Is it possible in sign up form to limit email input only to corporate emails such as @bp.com @kpmg.com etc so to eliminate non-business emails such as gmail.com yahoo.com etc? So that if user insert xxx@gmail.com the form rejects and ask to insert business emails? I saw such option when i applied for master and they required for recomendation to insert business emails.

What source you would advise to look for or what example of code you can share? If you can sharwe any would be great to have some idea.

My `forms.py` is

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username','email','password1','password2')
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a validator to your field to check the domain:

```py
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

domain_validator = RegexValidator(
    regex='@(bp\.com|kpmg\.com)$',
    message='Domain not valid',
    code='invalid_domain',
)

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(validators=[domain_validator])

    # ...
```

The regex can probably be improved, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any optimal way to do what you are trying to do, not in `django` because it's not exactly a `django` problem.

But, have said that we can do it in a kind of un-optimized way which is, we can create a black-list of emails such as `google`, `yahoo`, `hotmail` etc. 
As there're a huge number of such companies, we can not add them all at once because we don't KNOW them all. 
But with time, we can keep updating our blacklist and may be we can achieve with time what you are trying to achieve.
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502741/10190191) answer here, someone has given a link of a pre-created blacklist which has lots of such emails which you can add to your blacklist, but as I said earlier, this list can potentially never be complete.
Given you have this blacklist, you can check on form submission if the submitted email doesn't end with any of the emails in blacklist in simple `python`.

P.S: In my optinion, this does not really makes sense to do so given some small business have `gmail` addresses.